# How can i deploy my website on Heroku properly?

Tags: php, apache, heroku, model-view-controller, deployment

I've trying to deploy my website on Heroku, the implementation that i used for this it's Model View Controller with PHP. I don't know what happend but when i try to access to the main page (or index) this works perfectly, when i'm trying to access other pages on mi website something occurs like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26zCB.png)

I know one reason which this is happening, i used in my Router the next:

```
$currentURL = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/';
    //var_dump($_SERVER);
    
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    if($method === 'GET'){
        $fn = $this->routesGET[$currentURL] ?? null;
    } else{
        $fn = $this->routesPOST[$currentURL] ?? null;
    }
```

So, i displayed global variable of PHP $_SERVER on my website and i noticed `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` doesn't appear on it. So, i guess that the problem comes from Apache's configuration because i use Apache2 and PHP for this. So, i don't know how configure because it's my first time doing this, if you can help me, i'll really thank to you.

Here is my directory:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NVU8.png)

And, finally my procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the general appliable steps of configuring an MVC-based web application. Presumed web server version for the settings below: [Apache HTTP Server v2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/).

**1) Block access to all directories and files:**

First of all, in the config file of Apache, the access to all directories and files should be blocked by default:

```
# Do not allow access to the root filesystem.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

# Prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being viewed by Web clients.
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

**2) Allow access to a default directory:**

The access to a default directory (here `/var/www/`), ***supposedly*** used for projects, should then be allowed:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

***My recommendation***: For security reasons, this location should contain only a `index.php` and a `index.html` file, each of them displaying a simple *"Hello"* message. All web projects should be created in other directories and the access to them should be set separately, as described below.

**3) Set access to a separate project directory:**

Let's suppose that you create your project in another location (like in the directory `/path/to/my/sample/mvc/`) than the default one (`/var/www/`). Then, taking into consideration, that only the subfolder `public` should be accessible from outside, create a web server configuration for it, like this:

```
ServerName www.my-sample-mvc.com
DocumentRoot "/path/to/my/sample/mvc/public"

<Directory "/path/to/my/sample/mvc/public">
    Require all granted

    # When Options is set to "off", then the RewriteRule directive is forbidden!
    Options FollowSymLinks
    
    # Activate rewriting engine.
    RewriteEngine On
    
    # Allow pin-pointing to index.php using RewriteRule.
    RewriteBase /
    
    # Rewrite url only if no physical folder name is given in url.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    
    # Rewrite url only if no physical file name is given in url.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    
    # Parse the request through index.php.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</Directory>
```

Note that the above settings can be defined either:

- in the config file of Apache, or
- in a *.htaccess* file inside the project, or
- in a virtual host definition file.

In case a virtual host definition file is used, the settings must be included between the tags `<VirtualHost>` and `</VirtualHost>`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ... here come the settings ...
</VirtualHost>
```

***Note:*** Don't forget to restart the web server after each change of the configuration settings.

**Some resources:**

- [What is Options +FollowSymLinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120035/what-is-options-followsymlinks/26732503#26732503) (1)
- [What is Options +FollowSymLinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120035/what-is-options-followsymlinks/12129326#12129326) (2)
- [RewriteRule Flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)
- [Exposed folders in MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997912/exposed-folders-in-mvc-application/45998123#45998123)
- [mod_rewrite: what does this RewriteRule do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102128/mod-rewrite-what-does-this-rewriterule-do/2102189#2102189)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dakis. It seems to be that the problem came from .htaccess and my configuration about Apache. So, your answer is so complete and help me to fix this. Thanks for your support. Greeting.

Comment: @ÁngelCruz Hi. You are welcome. I'm glad that I could help. Good luck.